# how to find the position of a word in a sentence with start_index and end_index in Python

Tags: python, string, indexing, find

**Example 1 :**

```
start = 42
end = 48
string = "This is in line with others, showing that Noggin can function as a BMP-6 antagonist [21,22]."
```

---

```
Output = [9,9]
```

With the start index and the end index, how to return the index of the complete word ? (with the start position and at the end position it is the 9th word of the string)

---

**Example 2 :**

```
start = 42
end = 52
string = "This is in line with others, showing that Noggin can function as a BMP-6 antagonist [21,22]."
```

---

```
Output = [9,10]
```

Is this second case, more than one word is selected, so we need to return the index of the first word (Noggin) and the index of the last word (can).

---

**Example 3 (output is always 2 numbers) :**

```
start = 42
end = 61
string = "This is in line with others, showing that Noggin can function as a BMP-6 antagonist [21,22]."
```

---

```
Output = [9,11]
```

Output = [first_word_index, last_word_index]

---

**Example 4 (if a space is selected at the end, we don't care) :**

```
start = 42
end = 49
string = "This is in line with others, showing that Noggin can function as a BMP-6 antagonist [21,22]."
```

---

```
Output = [9,9]
```

---

**Example 5 (if a word is not completely selected) :**

```
start = 42
end = 51
string = "This is in line with others, showing that Noggin can function as a BMP-6 antagonist [21,22]."
```

---

```
Output = [9,10]
```

if a word is not completely selected, we act like it was completely selected

---

[image]

Comment: Do punctuation count towards the start index and end index?

Comment: It counts if there are spaces between the punctuation, else if the punctuation is stuck to the word we act like it is a whole word

Comment: So `start = 8`, `end = 10`, `string = "This... is in line with others."` returns `2`, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly, :) : output = [2,2]

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "the index of the complete word"? Are you looking for the number of spaces before the ``start``/``end`` index?

Comment: @RM Like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPA54.png

Comment: Thk guys, I added a picture to clarify the meaning

Answer (score 0):

The following function should work for any example:

```python
def words(start,end,string):
    c=1    
    l=[]
    for i in range(end):
        if string[i]==' ':
            c=c+1
        if i==start:
            l.append(c)
    if string[i]!=' ':
        l.append(c)
    else:
        l.append(c-1)
    return l
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression, finding all words, this returns a tuple of the indices:

```
from typing import Tuple

def word_index(string : str, start : int, end : int) -> Tuple[int, int]:
    import re

    word_re = re.compile(r'\w+')

    start_index = len(word_re.findall(string[:start+1]))
    end_index = len(word_re.findall(string[:end]))

    return start_index, end_index

word_index(42, 48) # (9, 9)
word_index(42, 52) # (9, 10)
word_index(42, 61) # (9, 11)
word_index(42, 49) # (9, 9)
word_index(42, 51) # (9, 10)
```